# Print on Elementary OS Loki

Tags: repositories

I have installed my Canon MF8280Cw printer on Elementary OS with the UFRII-driver (the same it worked in Linux Mint).
The problem is, that the job is sent, but the printer makes a beep and then nothing happens.
Do anybody have the same problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you install UFRII using the install.sh script? I'm having a similar issue but with the scanner. http://askubuntu.com/questions/827406/canon-mf229dw-wont-scan

Comment: Yes I used the UFRII - then took the suggested networkprinter; took the right driver, but it won´t print.
The printer makes a noise but it´s not printing...

How can I delete the installed UFRII driver, so that I can start from scratch?

Comment: Download the UFR installer/packages again. Go into 64bit/Debian folder and uninstall both .debs using Gdebi.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Canon_UFRII/UFRII_LT_Druckertreiber/

This was the line, that solves the printing problem:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6  libxml2:i386
```